White 1-px border remaining in trimmed gnuplot PNG export
I am exporting matrix-shaped data as an image via gnuplot.
However, after having made 0-sized margins and removed any border/tics, the export of NxM data results in a (N+1)x(M+1) image...
File test.txt
.1 .2 .3
.0 .3 .4
.4 .5 .6

Gnuplot script:
FILE="test"
set cbrange [0:1]
set margins 0,0,0,0
PADDING_PARM=1
unset tic
unset colorbox
unset border
stat FILE.".txt" matrix
set term png size STATS_size_y+PADDING_PARM,STATS_size_x+PADDING_PARM
set output FILE.".png"
plot  FILE.".txt" matrix u 2:($1*.064*sqrt(2)):3 with image notitle

If I use PADDING_PARM=0, there is one line and one column missing and an additional white border:

If I use the cheat PADDING_PARM=1, all the data is exported to PNG but the additional white border remains:

Is there a way to trim the image withion gnuplot? If not, is there a crossplatform one of doing it with an external tool?

OK, I should have rtfm of the png terminal.
The solution is
PADDING_PARM=1
set term png size STATS_size_y+PADDING_PARM,STATS_size_x+PADDING_PARM crop

